# Why am I getting different compiler behavior on const int used to specify array size?

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code:

```
static const int constant_int_value = 10;
static int my_array[constant_int_value];

int main(void)
{
  my_array[0] = 10;
}
```

clang gives a warning, but compiles it:

```
clang -Weverything -std=c11 array_index.c  
array_index.c:4:20: warning: variable length array used [-Wvla] 
static int my_array[constant_int_value];
                   ^ 
array_index.c:4:12: warning: size of static array must be an integer constant expression [-Wpedantic] 
static int my_array[constant_int_value];
           ^ 
2 warnings generated.
```

**It appears that I am using an integer constant, so I don't understand the warning.**

gcc does not compile the code:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c11 array_index.c
array_index.c:4:12: error: variably modified ‘my_array’ at file scope
 static int my_array[constant_int_value];
```

Comment: Just because you use const doesn't make it a constant. Weird, I know. use `#define constant_int_value 10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `constant_int_value` is not constant expression, even with `const` qualifier and static storage duration. You could have defined it as enum constant:

```
enum { constant_int_value = 10 }; // now, it is constant expression
```

When it is placed as array size, the compiler assumes, that it is VLA. However, VLAs are not allowed at file scope (I believe it's constraint violation), hence you get a warning or error.